# Change color part of text using index in flutter

Tags: flutter

I have a one String which contains words: `achievement admission advertise pencil`. I have a list with pairs of numbers:

```
class Pair<T1, T2> {
  final T1 a;
  final T2 b;

  Pair(this.a, this.b);
}
String letters = "achievement admission advertise pencil";
List<Pair> words = [Pair(3, 5), Pair(6, 8), Pair(9, 11), Pair(12, 14), Pair(15, 17)];
```

I want to change color part of String using index from which sign to which sign. For example after 2 seconds letters from 3 to 5 should have color green. After next 2 seconds only letters from 6 to 8 should be green, after next 2 seconds only letters from 9 to 11 should be green, rest letters should return to black. There is any way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can create a custom widget for this. Here is a working example:

(Use with `SyllableText(text: letters, parts: words)`)

```dart
class SyllableText extends StatefulWidget {
  const SyllableText({
    required this.text,
    required this.parts,
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final String text;
  final List<Pair> parts;

  @override
  SyllableTextState createState() => SyllableTextState();
}

class SyllableTextState extends State<SyllableText> {
  int currentPartIndex = 0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    Future.doWhile(() async {
      await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2));
      if (mounted && currentPartIndex < widget.parts.length) {
        setState(() => currentPartIndex++);
        return true;
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (currentPartIndex < widget.parts.length) {
      final part = widget.parts[currentPartIndex];
      final startText = widget.text.substring(0, part.a);
      final coloredText = widget.text.substring(part.a, part.b + 1);
      final endText = widget.text.substring(part.b + 1);
      return Text.rich(
        TextSpan(
          children: [
            TextSpan(text: startText),
            TextSpan(text: coloredText, style: TextStyle(color: Colors.green)),
            TextSpan(text: endText),
          ],
        ),
      );
    } else {
      return Text(widget.text);
    }
  }
}
```